# I genuinely think WolframAlpha has it wrong in this case

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image: WolframAlpha screenshot]

Please look at the screenshot above. Why is $\displaystyle z(\pi/2)=\frac{1}{2}\sin \pi$ not showing as $0$?

Comment: Look at the horizontal axis, it's not showing $t$ but $y(t)$. That's supposed to happen? I am unfamiliar with WA.

Comment: The graph is $z(t)$ vs $y(t)$. So, at $t=\pi/2$ you need to check if $(0,y(\pi/2))$ is in that graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha didn't think you wanted two functions of $t$ plotted against $t$; it's plotted $z$ against $y$, taking $t$ as a parameter. At $t=\pi/2$, $y=\pi/2+1$ while $z=0$; you'll see $(\pi/2+1,\,0)$ is on the curve.

Answer (score 2):

Check your axes: it looks like Wolfram is plotting $z$ against $y$, not $z$ against $t$.